# How to update post parent?

Tags: wp-insert-post

I have an array of image id's and i want assign them to the specific post:

```
foreach ($image_ids as  $image_id)
    var_dump(wp_insert_post(array('ID' => $image_id, 'post_parent' => $new_post_id), TRUE));
```

But there occurs error:

```
object(WP_Error)#252 (2) {
  ["errors"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["empty_content"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(38) "Content, title, and excerpt are empty."
    }
  }
  ["error_data"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

So is it possible to update the `post_parent` without updating other data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `wp_update_post()`, not `insert`.

```
wp_update_post(
    array(
        'ID' => $image_id, 
        'post_parent' => $new_post_id
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But in http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post is told that if ID exists - it updates current post...

Comment: Well, yes, the post_parent information is always stored in the child posts, not in the parent. So you have to update the image (post type `attachment`) to assign it to a parent post.

Comment: so i did this `wp_insert_post(array('ID' => $image_id, 'post_parent' => $new_post_id)`

Comment: I know that it's old discussion, but if you use wp_insert_post you need to specify all the fields. The fields that aren't in the arguments are updated with the default values. with wp_update_post you just need to specify the fields you want to change and all the other fields will keep the value.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Just you need to give your category or parent name before the postname in Custom Structure section

Comment: How is this related to the question?